# What is the purpose of the pam_stress module?

Tags: linux, pam

There is currently very little documentation for this Linux-PAM module, and I am struggling to understand what it might be used for?

### Reference

- [The Linux-PAM System Administrators' Guide](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html)
- [pam_stress README](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/master/modules/pam_stress/README)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CHANGELOG` in the PAM source](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/CHANGELOG#L1645) indicates it's for testing:

```
Saturday March 16 19:00:00 PST 1996 ( Andrew Morgan <morgan@physics.ucla.edu> )

        * added three modules: pam_permit pam_deny pam_stress
          no prizes for guessing what the first two do. The third is
          a reasonably complete (functional) module. Is intended for testing
          applications with.
```

The arguments seem to indicate what the module should return.